# stringbuilder append text with variables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this line, how do I append text with the varaibles to make up the headings?

```
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  week6 = model.SelectedSunday.AddDays(-7);
  week5 = week6.AddDays(-7);
  week4 = week5.AddDays(-7);
  week3 = week4.AddDays(-7);
  week2 = week3.AddDays(-7);
  week1 = week2.AddDays(-7);
  sb.AppendLine("Title, Total, " week6, week5, week4, week3, week2, week1 );
```

and also this code:

```
 var tradesmenReportData = _reportingService.GetTradeUKKPITradesmen(model.SelectedSunday);
  var jobSortedReportData = _reportingService.GetTradeUKKPIJobSorted(model.SelectedSunday);
  foreach (var item in tradesmenReportData)
  {
    sb.AppendLine(String.Concat("\"", item.Title, "\", item.Total, "\", item.Week6, "\", ", item.Week5, "\", ", item.Week4, "\", ", item.Week3, "\", ", item.Week2, "\", ", item.Week1));

  }
```

In the output file(excel), the values has a " appended to the values? Somewhere in above line there is an extra ".Where have I gone wrong?

thanks

Comment: It's hard to tell, since `"\"` won't work and the `String.Concat` isn't really readable. Is this the exact code? Perhaps you could try to use `String.Format("\"{0}\", \"{1}\"", item.Title, item.Total, ...)`.

Comment: yes it is and "\" is the delimiter for excel. I inherited this code. All  other code here that exports to excel has this format and it works, but headings are hardcoded.

Comment: @charlie_cat: This exact code wouldn't even compile, so I really don't think it is your actual code. `"\"` isn't a valid string literal, and the final line on the first section is missing a comma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sb.AppendFormat("Title, Total, {0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}", week6, week5, week4, week3, week2, week1 );
```

the AppendFormat overload will replace the place holders with the parameters you pass to the method (week6/week5 etc).

For the second snippet, you can use this again:

```
sb.AppendFormat("\"{0}\", \"{1}\", \"{2}\", \"{3}\", \"{4}\", \"{5}\", \"{6}\", \"{7}\"", item.Title, item.Total, item.Week6, item.Week5, item.Week4, item.Week3, item.Week2, item.Week1);
```

Comment: oops sorry I just tested it and for the heading part everything is in one cell except title and total as for the rest everything is on one line in the excel?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the excel behavior, but I guess you're missing the commas. I will fix the sample.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`StringBuilder.AppendFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cazfhf32%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
sb.AppendFormat("Title, Total, {0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}"
               , week6, week5, week4, week3, week2, week1);
```

> Appends the string returned by processing a composite format string,
>   which contains zero or more format items, to this instance. Each
>   format item is replaced by the string representation of a
>   corresponding argument in a parameter array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `StringBuilder.AppendFormat` as stated in other answers;

Another option (for example, when have `string` but not `StringBuilder`) you should use `string.Format`, as it is much more readable than `Concat`. For example:

```
sb.AppendLine(string.Format(@"\"{0}\" \"{1}\" \"{2}\" \"{3}\" \"{4}\" \"{5}\" \"{6}\" \"{7}\"", 
              item.Title, //0
              item.Total, //1
              item.Week6, //2
              item.Week5, //3
              item.Week4, //4
              item.Week3, //5
              item.Week2, //6
              item.Week1) //7
           );
```

Comment: the StringBuilder already have the AppendFormat overload, so using String.Format for the AppendLine method is a bit redundant.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I will leave this answer just as an example of string.Format for similar situations...